# How can I download attachments using EWS (Exchange Web Services) in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

I have a mechanism that downloads attachments from email messages sent into an inbox to a folder for processing by another service.

Originally this was done using some VBA that was triggered by a rule in Outlook. This wasn't build with large amounts of information going in originally however it has got to the point now that lots of data is being passed through and it is causing me headaches using this Outlook VBA and SSIS Package combination.

Therefore I am working on a new version built entirely in VB .NET, this obviously will mean its more robust and a lot easier to debug problems.

I have started using the EWS API and have managed to successfully connect to the Exchange and I am able to read the relevant messages and store their Subject etc. to variables.

I am struggling however to find ANY documentation / help regarding downloading of attachements with EWS with VB .NET code.

Everything seems to be in C# and I unfortunately have no experience with this. I am totally open to 3rd Party Solutions that may need to be purchased or even pointed in the right direction of a book or documentation, this is not being done on a shoe string and is quite important.

Answer (score 0):

Try converters between C# and VB.

Regarding EWS, many VB examples contains "[Exchange Web Services .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/index.html)". The same examples are in C# and VB

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.

I have looked at independantsoft before but there are no examples on how to download attachments, only how to attach and send or save as a .msg.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will get you started in the right direction. NOTE: I have not had a chance to test this VB code, since I do not have access to an Exchange 2007 server from home (as far as I know). However, I wrote this code carefully, basing it on C# code that I know works, because I used it at my workplace. See this link: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=105257. And this one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dd2b465b-b1d2-4c0d-82ec-c36c6c482d5d/populating-sql-server-from-emails?forum=sqltools

FURTHER NOTE: This code will DELETE each email after saving the attachments from it. I think it will be a hard delete as well. In other words, you won't be able to pull the emails back out of the Deleted Items folder. You have been warned.

(It is possible to just mark each email as read instead of deleting it, but I don't have time to write the code for that just now. Hopefully this will be enough for your needs. If you still need this question answered.)

```
Namespace StephenGTuggy.Examples.SaveEWS2007Attachments

    Public Module EWS2007ExampleMain

        Enum AuthenticationMethod
            Windows
            Basic
        End Enum

        Private Const sUserName As String = "SampleUserName"
        Private Const sPassword As String = "SamplePassword1"
        Private Const sDomain As String = "mycompany.com"
        Private Const eAuthenticationMethod As AuthenticationMethod = AuthenticationMethod.Basic
        Private Const sEWS_URL As String = "https://mailserver.mycompany.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
        'Private Const sEmailSender As String = "SampleUserName2@SomeOtherCompany.com"
        Private Const sSaveAttachmentsToDirectory As String = "C:\"

        Public Sub Main()

            ' Set up credentials to use to connect to the Exchange server.
            Dim nc As System.Net.NetworkCredential = Nothing
            Select Case eAuthenticationMethod
                Case AuthenticationMethod.Windows
                    nc = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
                Case Else
                    nc = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(sUserName, sPassword, sDomain)
            End Select

            ' Now bind to Exchange.
            Dim esb As New ExchangeWebServices.ExchangeServiceBinding
            esb.Url = sEWS_URL
            esb.Credentials = nc

            ' Main code....
            Dim findItemRequest As New ExchangeWebServices.FindItemType
            findItemRequest.Traversal = ExchangeWebServices.ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow

            ' Define which item properties Exchange should return for each email.
            Dim itemProperties As New ExchangeWebServices.ItemResponseShapeType
            itemProperties.BaseShape = ExchangeWebServices.DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties
            findItemRequest.ItemShape = itemProperties

            ' Identify which folders to search to find items.
            Dim folderIDInbox As New ExchangeWebServices.DistinguishedFolderIdType
            folderIDInbox.Id = ExchangeWebServices.DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.inbox
            Dim folderIDArray As ExchangeWebServices.DistinguishedFolderIdType() = {folderIDInbox}
            findItemRequest.ParentFolderIds = folderIDArray

            ' Limit result set to unread emails only.
            Dim restriction As New ExchangeWebServices.RestrictionType
            Dim isEqualTo As New ExchangeWebServices.IsEqualToType
            Dim pathToFieldType As New PathToUnindexedFieldType
            pathToFieldType.FieldURI = ExchangeWebServices.UnindexedFieldURIType.messageIsRead  '.messageFrom
            Dim constantType As New ExchangeWebServices.FieldURIOrConstantType
            Dim constantValueType As New ExchangeWebServices.ConstantValueType
            constantValueType.Value = "0"   'sEmailSender
            constantType.Item = constantValueType
            isEqualTo.Item = pathToFieldType
            isEqualTo.FieldURIOrConstant = constantType
            restriction.Item = isEqualTo
            findItemRequest.Restriction = restriction

            ' Send the request to Exchange and get the response back.
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Sending FindItem request....")
            Dim findItemResponse As ExchangeWebServices.FindItemResponseType = esb.FindItem(findItemRequest)
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Received response to FindItem request.")

            ' Process response from Exchange server.
            Dim folder As ExchangeWebServices.FindItemResponseMessageType = _
                CType(findItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items(0), ExchangeWebServices.FindItemResponseMessageType)
            Dim folderContents As ExchangeWebServices.ArrayOfRealItemsType = _
                CType(folder.RootFolder.Item, ExchangeWebServices.ArrayOfRealItemsType)
            Dim items As ExchangeWebServices.ItemType() = folderContents.Items

            For Each curItem As ExchangeWebServices.ItemType In items
                Dim iAttCount As Integer = GetFileAttachmentsCount(esb, curItem.ItemId)
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Subject: {0} DisplayTo: {1} DateTimeReceived: {2} ItemClass: {3} AttachmentCount: {4}", _
                                                          curItem.Subject.Trim(), _
                                                          curItem.DisplayTo.Trim(), _
                                                          curItem.DateTimeReceived.TimeOfDay.ToString(), _
                                                          curItem.ItemClass.Trim(), _
                                                          iAttCount)
                If iAttCount > 0 Then
                    GetAttachmentsOnItem(esb, curItem.ItemId, sSaveAttachmentsToDirectory)
                    If Not MarkItemAsProcessed(esb, curItem.ItemId) Then
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Unable to mark email as processed.")
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Finished processing emails and attachments.")

        End Sub

        Function GetFileAttachmentsCount(binding As ExchangeWebServices.ExchangeServiceBinding, _
                                         id As ExchangeWebServices.ItemIdType) As Integer

            Dim iAttachmentCount As Integer = 0

            ' Use GetItem on the Id to get the Attachments collection.
            Dim getItemRequest As New ExchangeWebServices.GetItemType
            getItemRequest.ItemIds = New ExchangeWebServices.ItemIdType() {id}
            getItemRequest.ItemShape = New ExchangeWebServices.ItemResponseShapeType
            getItemRequest.ItemShape.BaseShape = ExchangeWebServices.DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties
            Dim hasAttachPath As New ExchangeWebServices.PathToUnindexedFieldType
            hasAttachPath.FieldURI = ExchangeWebServices.UnindexedFieldURIType.itemHasAttachments
            Dim attachmentsPath As New ExchangeWebServices.PathToUnindexedFieldType
            attachmentsPath.FieldURI = ExchangeWebServices.UnindexedFieldURIType.itemAttachments

            ' Add additional properties?
            getItemRequest.ItemShape.AdditionalProperties = New ExchangeWebServices.BasePathToElementType() { _
                hasAttachPath, attachmentsPath}
            Dim getItemResponse As ExchangeWebServices.GetItemResponseType = binding.GetItem(getItemRequest)
            Dim getItemResponseMessage As ExchangeWebServices.ItemInfoResponseMessageType = TryCast( _
                getItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items(0), ExchangeWebServices.ItemInfoResponseMessageType)
            If getItemResponseMessage.ResponseCode = ExchangeWebServices.ResponseCodeType.NoError Then
                Dim item As ExchangeWebServices.ItemType = getItemResponseMessage.Items.Items(0)

                ' Don't rely on HasAttachments -- it does not mean what you think it would.
                If (item.Attachments IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (item.Attachments.Length > 0) Then
                    For attachmentIndex As Integer = 0 To item.Attachments.Length - 1
                        Dim almostAnAttachment As ExchangeWebServices.FileAttachmentType = TryCast( _
                            item.Attachments(attachmentIndex), ExchangeWebServices.FileAttachmentType)
                        If almostAnAttachment IsNot Nothing Then
                            iAttachmentCount = iAttachmentCount + 1
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If

            Return iAttachmentCount

        End Function

        Function MarkItemAsProcessed(esb As ExchangeWebServices.ExchangeServiceBinding, _
                                     id As ExchangeWebServices.ItemIdType) As Boolean

            Dim bReturn As Boolean = False

            ' Create the DeleteItem request.
            Dim dit As New ExchangeWebServices.DeleteItemType
            dit.ItemIds = New ExchangeWebServices.BaseItemIdType() {id}

            ' Delete the message.
            Dim diResponse As ExchangeWebServices.DeleteItemResponseType = esb.DeleteItem(dit)

            ' Check the result.
            If (diResponse.ResponseMessages.Items.Length > 0) AndAlso _
                (diResponse.ResponseMessages.Items(0).ResponseClass = _
                 ExchangeWebServices.ResponseClassType.Success) Then
                bReturn = True
            End If

            Return bReturn

        End Function

        Sub GetAttachmentsOnItem(binding As ExchangeWebServices.ExchangeServiceBinding, _
                                 id As ExchangeWebServices.ItemIdType, _
                                 destinationPath As String)
            ' STEP 1: We need to call GetItem on the Id so that we can get the Attachments collection back.
            Dim getItemRequest As New ExchangeWebServices.GetItemType
            getItemRequest.ItemIds = New ExchangeWebServices.ItemIdType() {id}
            getItemRequest.ItemShape = New ExchangeWebServices.ItemResponseShapeType

            ' For this example, all we really need is the HasAttachments property and the Attachment collection.
            ' As such, let's just request those properties to reduce network traffic.
            getItemRequest.ItemShape.BaseShape = ExchangeWebServices.DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly
            Dim hasAttachPath As New ExchangeWebServices.PathToUnindexedFieldType
            hasAttachPath.FieldURI = ExchangeWebServices.UnindexedFieldURIType.itemHasAttachments
            Dim attachmentsPath As New ExchangeWebServices.PathToUnindexedFieldType
            attachmentsPath.FieldURI = ExchangeWebServices.UnindexedFieldURIType.itemAttachments

            ' Add these to the list of properties to fetch....
            getItemRequest.ItemShape.AdditionalProperties = New ExchangeWebServices.BasePathToElementType() { _
                hasAttachPath, attachmentsPath}

            ' Now make the call.
            Dim getItemResponse As ExchangeWebServices.GetItemResponseType = binding.GetItem(getItemRequest)

            ' getItem returns ItemInfoResponseMessages. Since we only requested one item, we should only
            ' get back one response message.
            Dim getItemResponseMessage As ExchangeWebServices.ItemInfoResponseMessageType = TryCast( _
                getItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items(0), ExchangeWebServices.ItemInfoResponseMessageType)

            ' Like all good, happy and compliant developers [sic], we should check our response code....
            If getItemResponseMessage.ResponseCode = ExchangeWebServices.ResponseCodeType.NoError Then

                ' STEP 2: Grab the Attachment IDs from our item
                Dim item As ExchangeWebServices.ItemType = getItemResponseMessage.Items.Items(0)
                If item.HasAttachments AndAlso item.Attachments IsNot Nothing AndAlso item.Attachments.Length > 0 Then

                    Dim attachmentIds As New List(Of ExchangeWebServices.RequestAttachmentIdType)

                    For attachmentIndex As Integer = 0 To item.Attachments.Length - 1

                        ' For now, let's only consider file attachments instead of item attachments.
                        Dim almostAnAttachment As ExchangeWebServices.FileAttachmentType = TryCast( _
                            item.Attachments(attachmentIndex), ExchangeWebServices.FileAttachmentType)
                        If almostAnAttachment IsNot Nothing Then

                            ' VERY IMPORTANT! The attachment collection returned by GetItem only has meta data
                            ' about the attachments, but DOES NOT INCLUDE THE ACTUAL CONTENT. We must use 
                            ' GetAttachment to get the actual attachment.
                            Dim requestId As New ExchangeWebServices.RequestAttachmentIdType
                            requestId.Id = almostAnAttachment.AttachmentId.Id
                            attachmentIds.Add(requestId)

                        End If

                    Next

                    ' Now that we have all of the attachment IDs, let's make a single GetAttachment call to 
                    ' get them all in one shot.
                    Dim getAttachmentRequest As New ExchangeWebServices.GetAttachmentType

                    ' Oddly enough, just create an EMPTY (non-null) attachment response shape.
                    getAttachmentRequest.AttachmentShape = New ExchangeWebServices.AttachmentResponseShapeType
                    getAttachmentRequest.AttachmentIds = attachmentIds.ToArray()

                    Dim getAttachmentResponse As ExchangeWebServices.GetAttachmentResponseType = _
                        binding.GetAttachment(getAttachmentRequest)

                    ' Now, here we asked for multiple items. As such, we will get back multiple response
                    ' messages.
                    For Each attachmentResponseMessage As ExchangeWebServices.AttachmentInfoResponseMessageType _
                        In getAttachmentResponse.ResponseMessages.Items

                        If attachmentResponseMessage.ResponseCode = ExchangeWebServices.ResponseCodeType.NoError Then

                            ' We only asked for file attachments above, so we should only get FileAttachments.
                            ' If you are really paranoid, you can check for null after this again.
                            Dim fileAttachment As ExchangeWebServices.FileAttachmentType = TryCast( _
                                attachmentResponseMessage.Attachments(0), ExchangeWebServices.FileAttachmentType)

                            ' Now, just save out the file contents.
                            Using file As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileAttachment.Name))

                                file.Write(fileAttachment.Content, 0, fileAttachment.Content.Length)
                                file.Flush()
                                file.Close()

                            End Using

                        End If

                    Next

                End If

            End If

        End Sub

    End Module

End Namespace
```

One final note: You will use the same .asmx link both to create the web reference to EWS and to connect to the server to make the actual calls. This had me stumped for a bit.

Good luck!